# How to set where to download the VM in minishift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

It downloads openshift into `C:\Users\[user]\.minishift\machines` folder. How to change this location to, say, `D:\My VMs\`? The [`config set`](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/command-ref/minishift_config.html) is not very helpful in explaining setting which config for which.

- Minishift verision:  v1.15.1
- Platform: Windows
- Driver: Hyper-V

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `machines` directory can't be set directly through config. It is set relative to a base directory in [instance_dirs.go](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/blob/d9a86c9a994cb52b350bf0390b3215ad36c56487/cmd/minishift/state/instance_dirs.go#L48).

That base directory, by default, is the `.minishift` directory in the home directory of the user, e.g. `C:\Users\[user]\.minishift` on Windows, but this can be overridden by setting the environment variable `MINISHIFT_HOME`.

The base directory could also be a profile directory, if you are not using the default profile (the default being `minishift`).

```
$ minishift profile list
- minishift Stopped
$ minishift profile myprofile
Profile 'myprofile' set as active profile.
```

The `machines` directory for `myprofile` would then be created under `$MINISHIFT_HOME/profiles/myprofile/machines`, e.g. on Windows `C:\Users\[user]\.minishift\profiles\myprofile\machines`.

So you can set `MINISHIFT_HOME` and move the whole contents of the `.minishift` directory, including `machines`, somewhere else but it doesn't look like you can move just `machines` alone.

Perhaps, you could solve this at the OS-level by creating a [symlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) between `C:\Users\[user]\.minishift\machines` and `D:\My VMs\`.

Comment: +1 for symlink suggestion. Thank you for the reply. Also:
 1) I also found in the meantime from the devs that adjusting MINISHIFT_HOME might have side effects and is not officially supported
 2) You can move just the machines to a different location through hypervisor but reprovisioning might be tricky

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others and so they don't need to test the different ways of using symlink as well as to expand on @codemonkey great answer this is what I did to use symlink as my C drive had no available space.  I'm also using hyper-v as the driver.

**Note:** I do have minishift.exe installed in the apps folder on my D drive

**Note 2:** I did have to run the command prompt in admin mode

1. From the `C:\Users\[user]\.minishift` folder I moved the "machines" folder to `D:\Apps\minishift-1.32.0-windows-amd64\`
2. I first tried a soft link which didn't work, I then tried a hadr link, but I was getting errors so I used a "directory junction" link with the `/J` switch as such `C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink /J C:\Users\[user]\.minishift\machines D:\Apps\minishift-1.32.0-windows-amd64\machines`
3. You should get the following result `Junction created for C:\Users\[user]\.minishift\machines <<===>> D:\Apps\minishift-1.32.0-windows-amd64\machines`
4. Then if necessary run `minishift delete --clear-cache` **WARNING** this will delete any previous images and hosts you might have!
5. Then start minishift as normal with `minishift start`
6. Grab a cup of coffee or go smoke a cigarette or vape as it will take awhile for the OpenShift server to be started.

   Hope this answer might help others who face a similar issue.